# Automatic flowchart generator from files

Tags: c++, programming, diagram, flowchart

I need a flowchart program that can generate a flowchart from the source files, as I do not know the layout of the program.

I am aware of some programs that generate a flowchart from their own language or pseudocode such as graphviz or codetoflow.com, but those do not have what I am looking for.

[Code2flow by Scott Rogowski](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow) (not the same as code2flow.com and predates it) seems to be the closest thing I'm looking for, but it only supports Python and Javascript, which is very unfortunate.
I need it to support C++, but it'd also be nice it supported C#.

Comment: You say: "but it only supports Python and Javascript, which is very unfortunate." but don't specify which language you do need.

Comment: @albert C++, sorry

Comment: Did you see the posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310166/automatically-generate-flowcharts-out-of-c-code

Comment: @ablert I did, but it did not have what I was looking for.